# Cronjob Create File Every Execute

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, curl

I can create a cron job for every 5 minutes with following codes:

```
*/5  *  * * *   root    bash /etc/cron.d/mongo/5min.sh
```

In the **/etc/cron.d/mongo/5min.sh** file send request with **cURL**:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
curl http://mysite.com/crons/5minute
```

Routing of sent request site **crons/5minute** is php code and not does anything with file system but every executed times will create a file in the home directory like this format:

> 5minute
>
> 5minute.1
>
> ...
>
> 5minute.14999

Inside of these files exists what response's body of curl request. Like this:

```
empty<br>
yes<br>
```

These strings are written in crons/5minute.php with **echo** command.

What cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That is designed behavior. Curl adds a numerical suffix to the file name to distinguish results from run to run. Use -o option to override that

`curl http://mysite.com/crons/5minute -o  [/your/path/to/]5minute`

Comment: Can not do anything but cron program exists problem because I'm edit the crontab file and do comment line like this: `#*/5  *  * * *   root    bash /etc/cron.d/mongo/5min.sh` but continue to send request. I can restart cron like this: `sudo service cron restart` it stop/start but not exists any difference.

Comment: What is the crontab file you edit? Please provide full path.

If you modify crontab file directly, it may not acquire changes until restart. But if you modify it using `crontab -e` command it will bring up your editor (vim by default). There you can modify the file, when you save/exit,  changes applied right away. Make sure you run `crontab -e` being logged on as user you want to run crontask under.